# API Client permissions

Tags: api, sandbox, commerce-cloud, demandware

How can I create or how to obtain a 'Client Id' and 'Client Password' in order to authorize the API Explorer instance on the below URI?

https://api-explorer.commercecloud.salesforce.com/?url=https://staging.web.myinstancename.demandware.net/s/myinstancename/dw/meta/v1/rest

I also have a Demandware account, and when I log into the Account Manager, I cannot see the API Client tab (only 3 visible tabs: Account Information, Account Details, Password). My user has the following roles assigned:

- Business Manager Administrator
- Business Manager User
- Documentation User
- OCAPI Explorer Debug User
- Sandbox API User
- XChange User

What permissions do I need in order to create an API Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage client ID's, you need to be an Account Administrator for your organization.

There must be at least one account administrator that is assigned to your organization and you can ask them to do this for you. If you can not find this user, contact Commerce Cloud Support.

Here is a list of actions that you can do as an administrator user.
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/AccountManager/AccountManagerOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have these roles assigned:

```
* Business Manager Administrator
* Business Manager User
* Documentation User
* OCAPI Explorer Debug User
* Sandbox API User
* XChange User
```

But you're missing ***Account Administrator*** role. This is why you are not able to see the ***API Client*** tab along with the other 3 visible tabs.

As mentioned in a prior comment, you must be an account administrator for your organization.
Once you have that resolved, follow the steps below:
(Your admin can handle this for you as well)

- Login Account Manager `https://account.demandware.com/`

  - Check roles assigned to you, make sure that your user account has the `Documentation User` role assigned to access OCAPI.
  - Go to `API Client` tab, and select the `Add API Client` button.
  - API Client ID will be auto-generated for you, for example: `32423432hu32k3432g432`.
  - Create password, example: foo (this is your client password)

Client ID: 32423432hu32k3432g432.
Client Password: foo